# CD rom stepper getting warm

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor, a4988

I'm trying to run a SPS-15RF stepper motor from an old cd rom drive. I'm using a CNC shield and a4988 driver with a 6v power supply. The motion is smooth and fine. I know it has 18 pulse/revolution and works with 5v but It gets quite unexpectedly hot. It feels that it can burn my fingers if I keep it running.
What is wrong with it? is it related to micro-stepping or sth else!?[image]

[image]

Comment: Those motors are not designed to be constantly driven. They are designed to move to one position and then "release" (that is, the power is removed and active driving ceases).

Comment: there are many DIY projects on the web, using these motors for CNC applications which are somehow constant driven! there should be a solution.

Comment: Maybe you need to trim down the motor current at the driver. When the motor gets hot at continous use with the normal current, you could lower it, so that it doesn't get hot anymore

Comment: don't forget to "release" - disable driver when not actively moving (pin is called EN)

Comment: @chrisl How can I trim down the motor current?

Comment: Normally a stepper driver gas a little potentiometer on it, that you can rotate with a small screwdriver. That is used to set the motor current

Comment: Ok. I got it. current limit=Vref*2.5